# Add one more level to an existing CSS menu

Tags: html, css, menu

a friend of mine has a website and asked me to make some modifications on it. The problem is that there is a CSS menu(2 level) and i would like to make it a 3 level menu.

Here is the CSS for the menu

```
#nav{position:absolute;right:0px;bottom:0}
#nav a{height:23px;margin:0 0 0 1px;padding:7px 11px 0 12px;font-weight: lighter; font:14px helvetica,arial;color:#FFF;text-align:center;display:block;float:left}
#nav div{float:left}
#nav .hot{color:#fff;background:url(../images/nav-up-hot.png)}
#nav a:hover,#nav .aboutHover .button{background:url(../images/nav-up.png); color:#333; 
       /* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */
        /* ...but not required as filter works too */
        /* should come BEFORE filter */
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70)";

        /* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
        /* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
        filter: alpha(opacity=70);

        /* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
        -moz-opacity:0.7;

        /* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
        -khtml-opacity: 0.7;

        /* Modern!
        /* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
        /* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
        opacity: 0.7;

}
#nav ul li a:hover {color:#00b9ff}
#nav .about ul{display:none}
#nav .aboutHover ul{position:absolute}
#nav li{margin:0;padding:0;background:none !important}
#nav ul{width:180px;margin:30px 0 0 1px;*margin:30px 0 0 -120px;padding:4px 10px 4px 0;list-style:none;background: url(../images/sub-back.png);}
#nav ul a{width:100%;height:20px;padding:4px 0 0 10px !important;text-align:left;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;color:#FFF;background:none;display:block}
#nav ul a:hover{background:none}
```

And the HTML code is:

```
<div onmouseout="className='about'" onmouseover="className='aboutHover'" class="about">
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link( 1 ); ?> " title="Accommodation" class="button"><strong>Accommodation</strong></a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $permalink = get_permalink( 200 ); ?>" title="Room 1">Room 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $permalink = get_permalink( 203 ); ?>" title="Room 2">Room 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $permalink = get_permalink( 256 ); ?>" title="Room 3">Room 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $permalink = get_permalink( 89 ); ?>" title="Room 4">Room 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $permalink = get_permalink( 45 ); ?>" title="Room 5">Room 5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I tried a lot, searched the Internet but i couldn't find a solution as to how to add a new level.

Now the Menu is:

> **Accomodation**
>       L Room 1
>       L Room 2
>       L Room 3
>       L Room 4
>       L Room 5

What i want to do is:

> **Accomodation**
>          L *Sea View Rooms*
>                       L Room 1
>   
>                     L Room 2
>     
>                   L Room 3
>          L
>   *Land View Rooms*
>                      L
>   Room 4
>                      L Room 5

Thanks a lot for your help in advanced...

Comment: ... could you by any chance make a jsfiddle entry and post the link to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... sorry about the delay. So I fired up Firebug (...hm not sure if the pun is intended or not?!?) and inspected one of the menu items under accommodations, then clicked the 'edit' button and messed with it. Came up with this:

```
<li>
<a title="Cave Villa Alexandros" href="http://katsekala.com/marizanv2/cave-villa-alexandros/">
    Cave Villa Alexandros
</a>

<a href="#" style="color:red; margin-left:2em;">
    Some other link
</a>
```

Just added a link right under another link without wrapping it in anything ... the red color is just for visibility, left margin is what indented it. If I understand correctly that's all you need, right? Not a horizontal flyout. Since your **a** tags are displaying as 'block' you can put left-margins on them as needed. Holler if this is not what you meant.

Comment: well i actually wanted an extra popup div to display the sub categories inside. But this will work just fine. Thank you for the help!

Comment: ... hm, I do see that in your original question, my bad. However, I just looked at the site again, and see the menu works only with JS, so which script is running that? In all honesty, if that's the case you might me better off picking anther menu script rather than trying to make the current one int 3 level kind. And that could be styled easily to have transparency and. Here's a good list to pick from: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/ ...

Comment: ... these seem pretty neat: http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinydropdown2/       http://css-tricks.com/examples/SimplejQueryDropdowns/   css only: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/dd_valid.html    http://www.stunicholls.com/menu/pro_dropdown_2.html

Answer (score 0):

... something like this:

```
#nav ul li ul { margin-left: 25px; }
```

and subsequently for one more level down:

```
 #nav ul li ul li ul { margin-left: 25px; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you said and now whenever i mouse over "accomodation" both sub menus display on top of each other. I try adding a "#nav ul li ul {display: none}" but still doesn't work properly. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: ... that would simply indent the ul's, if you could drop a static version of it into jsfiddle, it would be easier to work out the bugs. Is this a css only menu or is there some js involved?

Comment: i tried creating a static version in jsfiddle but i couldn't do it.
Menu is located at http://www.katsekala.com/marizanv2 and css file is at http://www.katsekala.com/marizanv2/wp-content/themes/marizanv2/css/ModuleStyleSheets.css

Comment: ... can you restore to the original condition, I'll see if I can figure out that indentation, right now I'm just lost in that menu

Comment: restored... Thanks for trying to help me as i am lost also