# Trouble adding a 2nd sub level menu in a css only menu

Tags: html, css, menu

Ok, I've been at this for a little while and have my menu displaying correctly for the parent and children.. but I am trying to add a 2nd level of children and I can not get them to display. I thought it was a matter of adding the correct css and prefixing it with an extra UL LI  .. but obviously i'm wrong there.

The menu is living here at this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Q2tAk/

Ignoring the margins, they look fine combined with the other css.. I just cant get that 2nd sub level menu to show..  I thought it was similiar to this [other question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676588/add-one-more-level-to-an-existing-css-menu), but so far nothing..

```
Menu
   -- Child
       -- sub-child
```

Comment: Going to have to fight this more.. still not getting it the way I want it.. this is the original menu here if it helps: http://cssdeck.com/labs/skyrim-inspired-drop-down-menu

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, you need to use the css selector `>` on `<li>` and not on `<a>`

For example:

```
.first-level li > ul.second-level{
    display:block;
}

.second-level li > ul.third-level{
    display:block;
}
```

Hope that helps you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jsFiddle of the 2nd submenu showing](http://jsfiddle.net/U9Rf8/)

The issue was twofold. First, the 2nd sub-level wasn't showing because it was hidden behind the 1st sub-menu. This was occurring because they were both positioned in the same location using absolute positioning. To fix this, I altered the nested "#menu li ul" to be positioned in a relative fashion:

```
#menu li ul {
    position: relative; /*Changed*/
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    ...
```

The second issue was that both the 1st and 2nd submenus were being displayed when the  "#menu li:hover ul" event was triggered. In order to solve this, a direct-child selector can be inserted so that only the direct ul child of the hovered li will be displayed:

```
#menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: The only trouble there, is the menu items move around due to the relative positioning, which I would rather not have..

Comment: You can add a height parameter to the #menu li property --> #menu li {height: 50px;}